# PHP Pear library throws me error of "no DB selected"

Tags: php, database, pear

I have a below code snippet in my code:

```
    $dsn = DB_TYPE . '://' . DB_USER . ':' . DB_PASS . '@' . DB_HOST . '/' . DB_NAME;
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $db = DB::connect( $dsn, 'true' );
    $db->setFetchMode( DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC );
    function errhndl ( $err ) {
        echo '<pre>' . $err->message;
        print_r( $err );
        die();
    }

    PEAR::setErrorHandling( PEAR_ERROR_CALLBACK, 'errhndl' );
```

I have all DB credentials correct and also included the PEAR library for databse as well but still this throws me the below error:

```
DB Error: no database selected
```

and a DB error object array

Can someone guide me whats wronf with this?

Comment: You should probably post more code, as this snippet does not include any statement that might do a database operation that requires a selected database.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to access an existing database?